Proof that a rectangle is cut in half by any line through the center

Given rectangle ABCD with center O, prove that any line, $l$, that passes
through center O divides the rectangle in half.


The concept here isn't difficult, and the proof is not that complex. However, as I sought to prove this, I felt like my proof kept spiraling into more and more lemmas. I'll put my proof below - my question is, is there a more elegant way to prove this? Or, is there a way I can clean up my proof to make it more readable? I am open to suggestions, I'm not very experienced with proofwriting (especially not digitally).
Assumptions/relevant theorems:

Alternate interior angles theorem: If a transversal crosses two parallel lines, the alternate interior angles are congruent
Vertical angles theorem: opposite angles formed by intersecting lines are congruent
AAS Congruence: Two triangles are congruent if they have two congruent corresponding angles and one congruent corresponding side
A rectangle is cut in half by a line that goes through the midpoints of opposite sides
Congruent shapes have equivalent areas
The center of a rectangle is equidistant from opposite sides

Proof (using the picture above for reference):

$\angle{AXY} \cong \angle{CYX}$ (alternate interior angles)
$\angle{MOX} \cong \angle{NOY}$ (vertical angle theorem)
$\overline{MO} \cong \overline{ON}$ (assumption #5)
Rectangle \mathrm{AMND} is congruent to rectangle \mathrm{MBCN} (assumption #3)
$\triangle{MOX} \cong \triangle{NOY}$ (AAS congruence)
The area of quadrilateral $\mathrm{AXYD}$ is equal to $\mathrm{AMND} + \mathrm{MOX} - \mathrm{NOY}$
The area of quadrilateral $\mathrm{CYXB}=\mathrm{MBCN} + \mathrm{NOY} - \mathrm{MOX}$
$\mathrm{AXYD}=\mathrm{AMND}+\mathrm{MOX}-(\mathrm{MOX})=\mathrm{AMND}$ and $\mathrm{CYXB}=\mathrm{CYXB}+\mathrm{NOY}-(\mathrm{NOY})=\mathrm{CYXB}$ (substitution property of equality)
$\mathrm{AXYD}=\mathrm{AMND}=\mathrm{MBCN}=\mathrm{CYXB}$ (transitive property of equality)
Since the two areas are equal, the rectangle is cut in half, as was to be shown.


Your proof isn't that lengthy at all. The concepts are rather straightforward.

@BrevanEllefsen thanks for the affirmation. It's been awhile, so I'm not feeling as confident as I'd like. And the proof just doesn't feel elegant (but maybe it's hard to pull of an elegant geometric proof here).

Assume the center of the rectangle is at the origin. Define a symmetry operation which maps $(x,y) \rightarrow (-x,-y)$. It maps the line onto itself, and one part of the rectangle is mapped into the other (can be proven by checking every segment one by one). Because this operation is an isometry (preserves both angles and distances), the two halves are equal.
